# Как узнать принадлежит ли объект классу?

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, типы-данных, rtti

Как узнать принадлежит ли объект к классу pawn?
Не знаю на сколько глупый вопрос , просто у меня в методе  все наследники и их методы запускались через объект fi и мне нужно в одном из условий метода game исключить pawn, оставив других наследников.

```
class figure{};

class Pawn : public figure{};

class Game{

void metod(figure fi){
if(){ } // Как проверить fi на принадлежность к Pawn в if 
}; 

};
```

Comment: `dynamic_cast` не устроит? Только не передавайте по значению — по ссылке или через указатель.

Comment: Не совсем , что мне нужно. Возможно не правильно реализовываю.

Comment: Тут во время компиляции известно, что объект `fi` не является экземпляром `Pawn`.

Comment: В объект параметр с типом figure fi, можно передать  объект pawn тк он наследник. Сам пробовал все работает . 

Проблему решил используя  `typeid(fi) != typeid(pawns[0]),`

Comment: *"В объект параметр с типом figure fi можно передать объект pawn"* - нет, тип параметра строго задается сигнатурой функции. При попытке передать туда экземпляр `pawn` будет неявно создан новый экземпляр `figure` с вызовом конструктора копирования так как у вас в коде ошибка - конструкторы `figure` являются публичными и неявными.

Comment: Да , я ошибся. Забыл добавить в этом коде в функцию передачу по ссылке .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим ваш метод. И все же рассмотрим передачу по ссылке в дополнение к передаче по значению.

```
class figure
{
};

class Pawn : public figure
{
};

void value(figure fi)
{
    cout << "val typeid check: " << (typeid(fi) == typeid(Pawn)) << endl;
}

void refer(figure& fi)
{
    cout << "ref typeid check: " << (typeid(fi) == typeid(Pawn)) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Pawn p;
    value(p);
    refer(p);
}
```

[Ой](https://ideone.com/QQGyBw). Метод не работает в обоих случаях — говорит, что это `figure`. Почему? Да из-за отсутствия виртуальных функций, ergo, vtable, на которую опирается этот механизм RTTI.

Добавил виртуальность:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class figure
{
public:
    virtual ~figure(){}
};

class Pawn : public figure
{
public:
    virtual ~Pawn(){}
};

void value(figure fi)
{
    cout << "val typeid check: " << (typeid(fi) == typeid(Pawn)) << endl;
}

void refer(figure& fi)
{
    cout << "ref typeid check: " << (typeid(fi) == typeid(Pawn)) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Pawn p;
    value(p);
    refer(p);
}
```

Теперь метод [работает](https://ideone.com/BxzPnH) — но только при передаче по ссылке (а равно и через указатель, но я его тут не привожу), о чем я и писал в своем комментарии.

Но при наличии виртуальности можно применить и `dynamic_cast`, который, кроме прочего, дает возможность получить переданный объект типа `Pawn` — если он, конечно, передан. Я [тут](https://ideone.com/n9IW9R) специально проверяю через адрес, просто чтоб не возиться с обработкой исключения `bad_cast`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class figure
{
public:
    virtual ~figure(){}
};

class Pawn : public figure
{
public:
    virtual ~Pawn(){}
};

void value(figure fi)
{
    cout << "val typeid check: " << (dynamic_cast<Pawn*>(&fi) != nullptr) << endl;
    if (dynamic_cast<Pawn*>(&fi) != nullptr)
    {
        Pawn& p = dynamic_cast<Pawn&>(fi);
    }
}

void refer(figure& fi)
{
    cout << "val typeid check: " << (dynamic_cast<Pawn*>(&fi) != nullptr) << endl;
    if (dynamic_cast<Pawn*>(&fi) != nullptr)
    {
        Pawn& p = dynamic_cast<Pawn&>(fi);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Pawn p;
    value(p);
    refer(p);
}
```

Ну, а дальше — "думайте сами, решайте сами" (с)...